# Style simple PNG and iframe with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am stuck at a seemingly fairly simple issue:

I want to style a PNG and iframe hat I have added to my website, marked by id tags. They don't seem to care though. Both remain unaffected.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <style>

            #test{
              font-weight: bold;
            }

            #image1 {
              max-width: 80%;
            }

            #mb-map {
              width = 600px;
              height = 500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id = "test">test</p>
        <div id = "image1">
            <img src = "link to image">
            </img>
        </div>

    <iframe id = "mb-map"
        src='link to map supposed to be embedded' />

    </body>
</html>
```

The text with id = "test" is correctly styled as bold though.

Comment: CSS syntax is wrong and `img` is self closed tag.

Comment: @Manjuboyz, it's the HTML syntax, that's wrong. It should be <img src = "link to image" />. Also, there's alt parameter missing.

Comment: ahh, I see. ok that works now. I also modified to #image img {}
For the iframe it does not seem to help though

Answer (score 1):

1. Tag `img` has only opened tag. Also you missing `alt` attribute for `img` tag.
2. This is incorrect: `#mb-map { width = 600px; height = 500px; }`
   This is correct:
   `#mb-map { width: 600px; height: 500px; }`
3. Add the closed tag for `iframe` like this `<iframe></iframe>`
4. Also you missing the `title` tag in your `head`.

Correct code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #test {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    #image1 {
      max-width: 80%;
    }

    #mb-map {
      width: 600px;
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="test">test</p>
<div id="image1">
  <img src="link to image" alt="">
</div>
<iframe id="mb-map" src="link to map supposed to be embedded"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `#image1` is not the actual `img`, but it's surrounding `div`.

In your CSS, try `#image1 img { max-width: 80%; }`

---

For the `iframe`, your CSS is using equality sign instead of colon. Use this:

```
#mb-map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome @nextbear. I've edited the answer to include a fix for your iframe as well. If it works, pls upvote.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I must have been blind! All working now , many thanks fro the rapid reponses!